Identify 80's movie about monster from space
I am looking for a horror movie from the 80's in which a monster comes from space in a man-made space probe/ship that mysteriously comes back to earth. I think the monster looked like a centaur and was made with stopmotion technique. I watched it when I was a kid so maybe I'm mistaken. 
The most important point is the use of the unmanned ship to come to earth. At the end of the movie the monster is defeated but a lot of duplicates of the spacecraft are coming to earth.

I think you are describing Invader, (1996), aka "Lifeform".

When the Viking space capsule suddenly returns to Earth from its long
  ago trip to Mars, it brings with it an intelligent visitor that is
  part "Alien" and part "ET". Encased in armor, it extends a humanlike
  form from its shell to examine its surroundings and shows an interest
  in humans including a soft caress of a female scientist prior to the
  Army killing it. This only enrages its sibling.

When its upper body fully extends from its "shell" it does look somewhat like a centaur.

The movie is available on Youtube.

Yeah!!! That's it! Thank you! Now I can see that as a child I had a very active imagination, because some things are very different against my memories.
